# Center image after cropping

Tags: html, css

I cropped an imaging using clip then used the same id "image" to make more adjustment to it by centering the image on the page but can't seem to get it working. I tried using the code below and other methods but still can't get it to center. I'm assuming using the id again won't allow any further changes?

```css
#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 45px;
}

#image {
  object-fit: cover;
  Height: 400px;
  Width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  Clip: rect(20px, 674px, 1050px, 0px);
}

/*tried code below no luck getting it centred after cropping */
#image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#img-caption {
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
  <h1 id="title"> FLowers </h1>
  <figure id="img-div">
    <img id="image" src="https://live.staticflickr.com/4010/4680763568_0987b8f0a0_c.jpg" alt="single red flower" />
    <figcaption id="img-caption">
      Red Flower.
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
```

[webpage with image positioned to left instead of center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veqDm.jpg)

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: oh i see! cheers for that Rob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
figure {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

does the trick. If you want to clean the code a bit, you could rewrite it like so:

```
#title {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 45px;
}

#image {
   object-fit: cover;
   height: 400px;
   width: 400px;
   clip: rect(20px, 674px, 1050px, 0px);
}

figure {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
}
```